# Start ssh in background on OpenWRT via ssh

Tags: ssh, openwrt

Good morning,

I recently moved to the universities dormitory and they have a specific way how to enable the internet connection. They require me to connect to the network via Cable, set up a specific static IP and then enable the Internet connectivity by ssh'ing to a special IP with my own account and password. As long as this ssh session is open, the internet connection is active. If closed, then it is lost.

My setup right now is like this: I connected an OpenWRT-based TP-Link router (TP-Link TL-WR841N/ND v9) to the dormitory's network. My devices are connected to the router's wifi.

To get an internet connection, right now I am doing this:

- connect to the router via ssh
- connect to the internet via ssh on the router

So basically I am having two running ssh sessions. This is quite annoying as my laptop has to be on and running if I want to have an internet connection. My idea would be to keep the ssh session on the router running all the time. For this, however, I would need to keep the ssh session running in the background of the router.

Starting the second SSH with & skips the password entry. So I have to get it back to fg, enter the password and the process is back in the foreground. CTRL+Z appears to be not working on OpenWRT.

The only thing which could skip the password entry would be connecting with a key, but the server I am connecting to is not allowing that.

Anybody having other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple things to solve this

1. Create a script(which will connect to internet) in router and schedule it in a [cron job](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/cron)
2. If nohup/tmux is available in the router, execute the commands with them so that they keep alive when the ssh session is terminated.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment.
1. unfortunately does not work, as i can not "automatically" enter the password of the ssh user.
2. I am trying alternatives to this right now, but neither nohup nor tmux are available on my router.

Comment: Aha, thats simple, create a ssh key in router using "dropbearkey -t rsa -f .ssh/id_dropbear" copy the public key and set it manually in server .ssh/authorised_key file. once done ssh won't ask for passwords.

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like I solved the problem.

As nohup/tmux is not available on the router, I had to find an equivalent. Fortunately, screen is available for my router. With screen, you can start the ssh for the internet in a separate screen. When it's running, you can simply detach the screen and close the ssh to the router. 
The ssh-connection for the internet will continue running in the background of the router.

The only drawback is that I have to reconnect manually, as soon as the router restarts.